# Breaking up a csv file and recreating the arrays

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I don't need the you to do my work, just point me in the right direction.  I'm new to php and I think I can figure it out, I just need pointed in the correct direction on this.

I have a csv file with business info (company, address, city, email, etc.)

Some of the records have more than one email address in the email field.  Each value is separated by a semi-colon (;),

What I want to do is end up with each row having one email record.  If there was 3 email addresses in the original row, I need 3 rows each with one of the email addresses when I am done.

Most of the records have just one email address, but some have as many as 12 email addresses.

I know there are data normalcy issues here, but I am building a conversion utility to feed another application.

Again, I'm not looking for the final code, though I wouldn't turn it down ;), I am just looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks for the help...  Jeff

Answer (score 3):

at first, use [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read the file. this wil aotomatically plit the rows and columns:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))) {
    // do something
}
```

the you have to know wich field is the email-field (wich should be field `3` according to your list (3 not 4 because `$data` is a zero-based array)). use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split up the mail-adresses:

```
$emails = explode(";", $data[3]);
```

after that, you just have to nest the loops:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))) {
    $company = $data[0];
    $address = $data[1];
    $city = $data[2];
    $emails = explode(" ", $data[3]);
    foreach($emails as $email){
        // do something with $company, $address, $email...
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understood it, a row in the CSV file would be something like companyName,address,city,email1;email2  If that's the case, then the first parameter in the first explode() function should be ";"

Comment: THANK YOU!  Got it in no time at all.  Works like a dream.

Comment: @tomtheman5: thanks for the hint, that was just a typo and is corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

here is a tip. You have a CSV like this (company, address, city, email, etc.) And you said you had multiple emails separated by a DIFFERENT character, a semi-colon. Then you could think the field address to ve a "semi-colon"-separated value (a CSV but using a ; instead of a ,) like this email = (email1; email2; email3; etc.)

Tell me if you need more help